# Why does Stiyl Magnus have a bar code-like tatoo behind his eye?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

Stiyl Magnus has a bar code-like tatoo behind his eye. Why does he have it? Does it have a special meaning related to magicians?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on [this](https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Stiyl_Magnus) fandom-

> Stiyl promised that he will always protect Index whatever it takes, though it is unknown at which point in time he made this promise. **Stiyl also received his trademark barcode tattoo, ear piercing and rings after Index had her memories erased.**

Apart from this I don't think any special significance is ever mentioned as it would have surely been reported on the fandom and other sites.